# Comparative statics on $c/r$ using fundamental asset pricing equation

Tags: fixed-income, bond, asset-pricing, continuous-time

Consider the fundamental asset pricing equation for a perpetual coupon bond:

$$rP = c + \mu P' + \sigma^2/2 P''$$
with standard boundary conditions $P(\bar x) = \bar x$ and $\underset{x\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} P(x) = c/r$. $r$ is the interest rate and $c$ is the coupon rate, the other parameters are drift and volatility of the GBM of the underlying asset.

How can I derive how does the price change as a function of $c/r$? Notice that the closed-form solution does not help much, as $r$ enters the roots of the characteristic equation.

Comment: Why doesn't the closed form solution help? For a standard geometric Brownian motion, set $\beta_\pm=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{r-\delta}{\sigma^2}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{r-\delta}{\sigma^2}\right)^2+\frac{2r}{\sigma^2}}$ if $r-\delta$ is the risk-neutral drift, i.e., $\beta_\pm$ solve the characteristic equation $\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\beta(\beta-1)+(r-\delta)\beta-r=0$. [You can adjust accordingly to your needs.] Then, $\frac{\partial \beta_+}{\partial r}<0$. That should help when you use the chain rule.

Comment: Because I'm moving $c/r$, not $r$! I agree on your point though.

Comment: To be clearer, I'm not saying that $r$ is increasing or decreasing. $c/r$ might be going up regardless of the direction of $r$.